# JavaScript libraries compiled for both ES5 and ES6 targets

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, package.json, ecmascript-5

I have two applications written in TypeScript:

- First is an application for not controlled environments so we have compiler's target set to ES5 for better compatibility.
- Second is an application with compiler's target set to ES6. The application runs on machines with latest Google Chrome so that works just well.

The main point of interest here is our library (a separate npm package) with some common funcionality that is used in both applications (as their dependency). The challenge is that the library has its target set currently to ES5, but I would like to start using ES6 funcionality like native classes without having them transpiled to ES5 for the ES6 application.

What occured to me that I can do:

1. Instead of having one `dist/` directory for compiled sources of the library, I can start compiling it to both ES5 and ES6 (and have something like `dist/es5/` and `dist/es6/`) so each application can choose its version when importing the modules. This probably solves the problem but it does not feel so pretty to me. For example, I suppose that importing the symbols in IDE gets nasty since every exported variable or type exists twice.
2. Or, I can compile the library to ES6 only but then in the first project I need to start using babel for transpiling the library's ES6 code to ES5. This probably also solves the problem but it also means the application's devstack gets complicated (and maybe slower?).

So my question is: What would be the best practise here? What is the industry standard?

Is it common that libraries in npm registry are always compiled to ES5 and that the industry has just not started to use ES6 yet? Or is it common that libraries can be written, compiled and published in ES6, but you are always expected to use babel in your application for environments where ES6 is not available? Or is there some third approach I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: "Dual publishing" (i.e. including both versions in the package) would make sense to me. https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html has a bunch of information about this.